# Two faces-config files in JSF project

Tags: jsf, jdeveloper

I'm new to JDeveloper, I noticed when I created my first project that there are two `faces-config` files created as in the structure shown in the picture, Why there are two of them here ?

[image: JSFApplication]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the default way the projects are created.
You created a new JSF page or task flow in the Model project, basically indicating to JDev to treat the Model project as a Web project.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are two different web projects, as I can see there are different `web.xml` as well.